# Magento HOW TO Index only updated products

Tags: php, magento, indexing

I am building a database Magento based eShop, this question is above how to do effective indexing. I want to index **only** products that were updated/added.

Will this be the case if I set `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL` when importing? Then set it back to `Index on Save` and then reindex?

I am concerned about Magento 1.9.x

Comment: This depends largely on the version of Magento you run. Some versions support partial reindexing, some don't :)

Comment: I have updated my question with version info: 1.9.x

Comment: I believe that partial reindexing is only available in the enterprise edition. You could probably find an extension to do it though. You'll also probably get a better response at [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) since this question is pretty specific.